# insert multiple values into multiple rows with prepared statement PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert data from a multiselect into a database with multiple rows.

I once managed to insert them all into ONE row, each with a comma which is not really good from the database perspective.
The data from the multiselect is stored as an array in a variable, which then should be filled into multiple rows in the database with a foreach loop.

```
$array = implode((array)$_POST['multiselectdata']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_example (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
    ....
    exit();
}
else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $array, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result= mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo $row["column1"];
    }
    exit()
}
```

As a result in each row there should be 1 value displayed of the array in column1 and in column2 there is always going to be the same id. Currently this only inserts 1 value into the database and only 1 row

Comment: If you want to insert multiple rows, why do you execute that query only once?

Comment: mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); should be in the foreach loop that was my fault. Topic is answered perfectly below by Nick. This can be done with a foreach loop with an array or either with explode if the values are all available seperated with a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than implode the contents of `$_POST['multiselectdata']` you can iterate over it as an array and execute your prepared statement for each value in the array:

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
    // ....
    exit();
}
else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $value, $id);
    foreach (explode(',', $_POST['multiselectdata']) as $value) {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

Note that calling `mysqli_stmt_store_result` on an `INSERT` query makes no sense as there is no result set. That line and the `foreach` loop following should be removed from your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately it is not quite working yet. The data in $_POST['multiselectdata'] is stored like this: 1,2,3,6. Do I need to mention the "," for the foreach loop to work properly?

Comment: @RobinP sorry I thought from your code that `$_POST['multiselectdata']` was an array. In that case you will to `explode` it. See my edit.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I also got confused first, because I initially thought it would be an array. It works fine now